# Why is my initial ViewController not showing up on simulator only Hello World?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am following the Udemy Advanced iOS and Firebase tutorial. His tutorial is on ios 8 and I am on 10, plus I am on  Xcode 11.3 and he is on 9 I think.

Anyway, I followed the tutorial and when I launch it I get an error about LaunchScreen cannot  use custom classes. So I unchecked use as Launch Screen. This now allows the simulator to run, but when it does I don't see the app I have built. All is show is a white screen with "Hello World" on it?

For some reason when I created a Single View app in Xcode it only created a LaunchScreen.storyboard so that is where I built my UI. I have noticed other tutorials Xcode automatically creates the Luanch storyboard and the Main storyboard?

Comment: One thought is you created a SwiftUI app instead of a UIKit app. SwiftUI apps (1) do not contain any storyboards except `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and (2) automatically create a file called `ContentView.swift`, which has an `include SwiftUI` in it. When creating a new project in Xcode 11, the second screen - the one where you give your project a name - there's a dropdown called User Interface. Make sure you have `Storyboard` selected, not `SwiftUI`. Finally understand the Xcode will keep this value for the next project you create.

Comment: One last thing that indicates this - a "Storyboard" or UIKit app contains an "empty" view controller, that is, a VC with an empty view. A "SwiftUI" app has a view called ContentView that contains a Text view with "Hello World" in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you see the "Hello, World!" is you have created a SwiftUI app

For Xcode 11

When creating a new Xcode project and the user interface option is selected as **SwiftUI** as shown below

[image: SwiftUI Option]

Then the initial project files will only contain the  LaunchScreen.storyboard and the other files listed below. To configure the UI one needs to write SwiftUI code in the **ContentView.swift**

[image: SwiftUI Files]

When creating a new Xcode project and the user interface option is selected as **Storyboard** as shown below

[image: Storyboard Option]

Then the initial project files will contain the **LaunchScreen.storyboard** and the **Main.storyboard** as shown below.

[image: Storyboard Files]